# Total Count of column value in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Two tables, 
TableA and TableB with column "filename" which has same value in both table.

only the number of occurance of data is different.

e.g

```
|###TableA#########| 

|id|filename_TableA|
|01|file1          |
|02|file1          |
|03|file2          |
|04|file2          |
|05|file3          |
|06|file4          |

|## TableB ########|

|id|filename_TableB|
|01|file1          |
|02|file1          |
|03|file1          |
|04|file2          |
|05|file2          |
|06|file3          |
|07|file3          |
|08|file4          |
|09|file4          |
```

I need to generate a SQL query which shows the distinct filename with there

number of count and totalcount of the distinct filename.

like this:
[image]

using `select count(distinct filename_TableA) as totalCount from TableA`
gives the totalCount of filename but I am not able to generate the sql query for above result output.

Tried for single table:

```
select 
filename_TableA,
count(filename_TableA)as filecount_TableA,
totalCount = (
                select count(distinct filename_TableA) from TableA
             )
from TableA
group by filename_TableA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to break your problem into smaller parts!

Your question consists of two parts:

1. Get distinct files and counts from tableA
2. Get distinct files and counts from tableB

We write queries:

1.

```
SELECT filename_TableA, COUNT( * ) AS filecount_TableA
FROM TableA
GROUP BY filename_TableA
```

2.

```
SELECT filename_TableB, COUNT( * ) AS filecount_TableB
FROM TableB
GROUP BY filename_TableB
```

Check that the results of each individual query are correct.

Then we combine the queries:

```
SELECT filename_TableA, filename_TableB, filecount_TableA, filecount_TableB, ISNULL( filecount_TableA, 0 ) + ISNULL( filecount_TableB, 0 ) AS totalCount,
    COUNT(*) OVER() AS UniqueFileCount
FROM
        ( SELECT filename_TableA, COUNT( * ) AS filecount_TableA
        FROM TableA
        GROUP BY filename_TableA ) AS A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
            ( SELECT filename_TableB, COUNT( * ) AS filecount_TableB
            FROM TableB
            GROUP BY filename_TableB ) AS B
        ON A.filename_TableA = filename_TableB
```

**Note:** To cover scenarios where a file name may appear in one table but not the other I have used `FULL OUTER JOIN`.
If you do not have such a scenario i.e. each file name will appear at least once in every table, then you should use `INNER JOIN` as it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me with your answers and adding two more column output (totalCount & UniqueFileCount) to the solution.